# How to construct an SVG overlay over a div to give each side a drop target?

Tags: svg, overflow, clip-path

I'm trying to create an overlay to place over an *arbitrarily-sized* `div` to provide it with four drop targets—each one corresponding to a side of the `div`'s rectangle. The geometry of the drop targets should be such that a dropped element will go to the *closest* side of the div. This means a short, wide `div` will have trapezoidal top and bottom drop targets and triangular left and right drop targets, whereas a tall, narrow div will have triangular top and bottom drop targets and trapezoidal left and right drop targets (and a square div will have all triangles).

Here is the nested SVG I am trying to use for my overlay and the HTML it is overlaying along with its CSS:

```
#overlaid {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid lightgray;
}

#overlay {
  --overlay-visibility: visible;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999999;
  visibility: var(--overlay-visibility, hidden);
}

svg {
  stroke: black;
}

path:hover {
  fill: yellow;
}
<div id="overlaid">
  <svg id="overlay">

    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin">
      <path id="above-zone" d="M 0,0
                               L 100,0 50,50
                               z" fill="rgba(0,127,255,0.5)" />
    </svg>

    <svg viewbox="0 0 50 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
      <path id="before-zone" d="M 0,0
                                L 50,50 0,100
                                z" fill="rgba(255,0,127,0.5)" />
    </svg>

    <svg viewbox="0 0 50 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid">
      <path id="after-zone" d="M 50,0
                               L 50,100 0,50
                               z" fill="rgba(0,255,127,0.5)" />
    </svg>

    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax">
      <path id="below-zone" d="M 0,50
                               L 50,0 100,50
                               z" fill="rgba(255,127,0,0.5)" />
    </svg>

  </svg>
</div>
```

I have two issues with this that I don't know how to solve. First, when the arbitrarily-sized `div` is not square (it could be any size—and could change), I don't know how to clip the triangles on the longer sides into trapezoids down the center of the `div`. This is what I get with the above code:

[image: Top and bottom triangles overlap. How do I clip them into trapezoids so they don't overlap?]

And that issue may be leading to the second issue, which is when the `div` is either *very* short or *very* tall with respect to its width, the nested SVGs on the longer sides begin to shrink (presumably because they bump into the other side of the outer SVG (instead of overflowing). This is what I get when I set the `#overlaid` `height` above to `200px` in the above code:

[image: This is what I get when the height is very small with respect to the width. How do I get the triangles to overflow instead of shrink?]

So, how do I clip overlapping triangles into trapezoids so they don't overlap down the middle, and how do I get the triangles to overflow the outer SVG instead of shrink?

Other approaches are welcome, too, but remember, the overlaid rectangle size is arbitrary and the drop targets need to be able to receive drop events. I am also going to want to apply styling to these drop targets to indicate when they are active and to indicate when they are being hovered over, so please make sure your approach does not prevent that.

Here's what it should look like when it is shorter than it is wide (400x200 in this case).
[image: Shorter than wide]

Here's what it should look like when the outer `div` is stretched taller to make it square (400x400 in this case).
[image: Square]

And finally, here's what it should look like when the outer `div` is stretched taller than it is wide (400x800 in this case).
[image: Taller than wide]

Comment: Using one svg would likely be easier.

Comment: Is that possible? As the overlaid rectangle changes dimensions, the four drop targets will need to change shape, not only the length of the base of the triangle, but also via any clipping that morphs them from a triangle into a trapezoid.

Comment: I hope I understand you. I would use only one svg element  for all the shapes. Something like <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"  width="100%" height="auto">. In CSS the parent div must have position: relative;.  and for the svg you can have  `svg {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` Please observe that preserveAspectRatio="none" will distort the shapes inside svg

Comment: I have updated the question to include images for clarification.

Comment: Please note that each of the areas contains all the points that are closest to that side. That is a requirement. That also means the angles at the corners must remain at 45°—they may not be distorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem if the shapes overlap, as [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) will only be handled by the uppermost one. So all you have to care about is that shapes are stacked in such a way that for each side the intended triangular and trapezoid areas are on top of all others.

To counteract the overlap of the triangles at the left and right sides, they are swapped with the top and bottom rectangles if the aspect ratio of the div gets below 1. For this to work, you have to take advantage of the new [container query feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries). It is now implemented in all browsers, but be sure to check [minimum versions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container#browser_compatibility).

```js
const overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay');
const feedback = document.querySelector('#feedback')

overlay.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
  const side = [...event.target.classList]
               .find(cl => cl.endsWith('zone'));
  if (side) {
    feedback.textContent = side;
  }
});

overlay.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
  feedback.textContent = '';
});
```

```css
#overlaid {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  height: 100px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid lightgray;
  container-type: size;
}

#overlay {
  --overlay-visibility: visible;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999999;
  visibility: var(--overlay-visibility, hidden);
}

.wide {
  display: inline;
}

.high {
  display: none;
}

@container (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  .wide {
    display: none;
  }

  .high {
    display: inline;
  }
}

path, rect {
  stroke: black;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}

.above-zone {
  fill: rgba(0,127,255,0.5);
}
.below-zone {
  fill: rgba(255,127,0,0.5);
}
.before-zone {
  fill: rgba(255,0,127,0.5);
}
.after-zone {
  fill: rgba(0,255,127,0.5);
}

path:hover, rect:hover {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlaid">
  <svg id="overlay">

    <rect class="wide above-zone" width="100%" height="50%" />

    <rect class="wide below-zone" y="50%" width="100%" height="50%" />

    <rect class="high before-zone" width="50%" height="100%" />

    <rect class="high after-zone" x="50%" width="50%" height="100%" />

    <svg class="wide" viewBox="0 0 50 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid">
      <path class="before-zone" d="M 0,0 L 50,50 0,100 z" />
    </svg>

    <svg class="wide" viewBox="0 0 50 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid">
      <path class="after-zone" d="M 50,0 L 50,100 0,50 z" />
    </svg>

    <svg class="high" viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin">
      <path class="above-zone" d="M 0,0 L 50,50 100,0 z" />
    </svg>

    <svg class="high" viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax">
      <path class="below-zone" d="M 0,50 L 100,50 50,0 z" />
    </svg>

  </svg>
</div>

<p id="feedback">
```